# Share Drive with user permissions between Azure Virtual Machines

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage

I am currently looking into mapping multiple VMs in Azure with a local redundant storage account as a shared drive. So far, this is not the problem.

What I know and want until this point is explained here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows

But now I am using an on-premise AD where those machines are connected and joined into a domain. When a user logs in I would like to have that the mapped drive of the storage account always only shows the files that belong to that user. Currently I would understand that any user using the mapped drive would be able to see files of all user.

Can I achieve the requirement above with storage accounts and Azure VMs (with windows 10 / W Server 2016 at least)? If not is there a approach where I could achieve this without too much overload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [Azure File Sync](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/score-one-for-the-it-pro-azure-file-sync-is-now-generally-available/).

Azure File Sync replicates files from your on-premises Windows Server to an Azure file share. With Azure File Sync, you don’t have to choose between the benefits of cloud and the benefits of your on-premises file server - you can have both! Azure File Sync enables you to centralize your file services in Azure while maintaining local access to your data.

Comment: That means I do not map the storage account directly to the OS in the VM, but instead I use Azure file share, that syncs and connects both resources?

Comment: yeah, like that